# Pick image from library and compress windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

In this code first I am picking image from windows phone photo library and then compressing it so that I can upload it. But I am facing some problem in compressing as when I use FlushAsync in BitmapEncoder, the orginal final is not overwritten and exception occurs. Here is my code

Picking image from library

```
ImagePath = string.Empty;
                    FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
                    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
                    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

                    // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
                    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
                    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
                    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
                    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
                    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
                    filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
                    view.Activated += viewActivated;
```

Decoding and compressing image

```
FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;
        if (args != null)
        {
            try
            {
            if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;
            view.Activated -= viewActivated;
            userLoginResponse = await DataManager.GetLoginResponseAsync();
            for (int no = 0; (no < args.Files.Count && no < 4); no++)
            {
                StorageFile storageFile = args.Files[no];
                var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

                var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
                var data = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

                BitmapPropertySet propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();
                BitmapTypedValue qualityValue = new BitmapTypedValue(1.0, Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.Single);
                propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);
                BitmapEncoder be = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);
                be.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, 480, 480, 50, 50, data);
                await be.FlushAsync();
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I used the Nokia Imaging SDK to accomplish this. Just add the SDK to your solution [using NuGet.](http://web.archive.org/web/20150513083035/http://www.nuget.org/packages/NokiaImagingSDK/)
Then include

```
using Lumia.Imaging;
```

in your code file. After that you can use the following code to read the Image data from a `StorageFile` and compress it to a `byte[]` which you can then upload to your Server:

```
byte[] compressedImageBytes = null;
IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read); // "file" being the StorageFile from your FileOpenPicker
if (file.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg") || file.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpeg"))
{
    using (StreamImageSource source = new StreamImageSource(fileStream.AsStreamForRead()))
    {
        IFilterEffect effect = new FilterEffect(source);
        using (JpegRenderer renderer = new JpegRenderer(effect))
        {
            renderer.Quality = 0.7; // higher value means better quality
            IBuffer buffer = await renderer.RenderAsync();
            Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffer, out compressedImageBytes);
        }
    }
}}

if (compressedImageBytes != null)
{
    //you can upload or safe the byte-array of the compressed image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying in your application to select photos from a photo library of Windows Phone, compress them and write back to the library Windows Phone?

I know from your application you can only choose to read pictures from the photo library for Windows Phone. In this way, you cannot change the original  image on your Windows Phone photo library.

Comment: I don't want to change image in my photo library. I just want to compress the photo so that I can upload it as I can upload only that image which is less than 2MB

Answer (score 0):

Though it is late but I think the problem is using stream object multiple time. first you are using the stream to create the BitmapImage and after than using stream to create decoder and after this using the stream again in bitmap encoder. 
The funny thing is in Windows phone 8.1 stream object getting null after first time use. so you can clone stream object before using it. in your case you can clone 2 times for decoder & encoder like 
var streamDecoder= steam.Clone(); var streamEncoder = stream.Clone(). and use them in your decoder and encoder. I think the problem will be fixed like this.